# Split column datetime values with into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.2

With a MySQL query, how can I take a table like in Example A:
Example A

| ID | time | log_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2021-06-01 07:13:42.000000 | IN |
| 1111 | 2021-06-01 17:13:42.000000 | OUT |
| 1111 | 2021-06-03 07:00:42.000000 | IN |
| 1111 | 2021-06-03 17:00:42.000000 | OUT |
| 2222 | 2021-06-01 07:13:42.000000 | IN |
| 2222 | 2021-06-01 17:13:42.000000 | OUT |
| 2222 | 2021-06-03 07:00:42.000000 | IN |
| 2222 | 2021-06-03 17:00:42.000000 | OUT |

And create a view like Example B?
Example B

| ID | Date | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2021-06-01 | 7:13 am | 4:30 pm |
| 1111 | 2021-06-02 | NA | NA |
| 1111 | 2021-06-03 | 7:00 am | 4:00 pm |
| 2222 | 2021-06-01 | 7:13 am | 4:30 pm |
| 2222 | 2021-06-02 | NA | NA |
| 2222 | 2021-06-03 | 7:00 am | 4:00 pm |

Comment: Does your data is always consistent (only 2 rows per `id` per day, one with `in` and one with `out`)?

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: yes only 2 rows per day
10.2.36-MariaDB-1:10.2.36+maria~bionic-log

Comment: SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(MAX(case when log_type = ''',
      log_type,
      ''' then time end),"") AS `',
      log_type, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  `tabEmployee Checkin`;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT employee, employee_name, DATE(TIME), ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM `tabEmployee Checkin` 
                   GROUP BY DATE(TIME)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

Comment: I tried that already but data is in consistent

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Where does `4:00 pm` and `4:30 pm` for `OUT` value comes from? I only see `17:13:00` and `17:00:00`.. whereby hour 17 = 5 p.m .. even if you were mistaken in converting 24hr to 12hr time format, how does `17:13:00` (or `16:13:00`) turn to become `4:30 pm`? Any rules like _"if OUT time is more than 17:00 then round it to the next half-hour mark"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT MIN(DATE(`time`)) `date`, MAX(DATE(`time`)) maxtime
          FROM test
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY, maxtime
          FROM cte1
          WHERE `date` < maxtime ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT id
          FROM test )
SELECT cte2.id, 
       cte1.`date`, 
       COALESCE(TIME(t1.`time`), 'N/A') `IN`,
       COALESCE(TIME(t2.`time`), 'N/A') `OUT`
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
LEFT JOIN test t1 ON t1.id = cte2.id 
                 AND cte1.`date` = DATE(t1.`time`) 
                 AND t1.log_type = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = cte2.id 
                 AND cte1.`date` = DATE(t2.`time`)
                 AND t2.log_type = 'OUT'
ORDER BY 1,2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=51236ef22fcaaba3f2d9af9acf7f6c55

---

> where do we put our variable, to return from_date to_date – Ashanti

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT '{from_date}' `date`
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          FROM cte1
          WHERE `date` < '{to_date}' ),
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate your effort, I got error message

    Query: WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS ( SELECT MIN(DATE(`time`) `date`, MAX(DATE(`time`)) maxtime FROM `tabEmployee Checkin` UNION ALL SELECT `...
    
    Error Code: 1064
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`date`, MAX(DATE(`time`)) maxtime
              FROM `tabEmployee Checkin`
        ...' at line 2

Comment: @Ashanti Updated and fixed. Fiddle added.

Comment: yes working now, when I delete all records. the N/A is not working sir

Comment: We need a N/A to the day that no  IN and OUT, see row 2 and 5 per ID

Comment: @Ashanti Updated, check.

Comment: Yes sir N/A is Working now, and where do we put our variable, to return from_date to_date. we have from_date = filters.get('from_date')
    to_date = filters.get('to_date') which is call in query time BETWEEN '{from_date}' AND '{to_date}'

Comment: I got error message "IndexError: tuple index out of range" when implement the query

Comment: @Ashanti *where do we put our variable, to return from_date to_date.* Use them in `cte1` instead of selection from source table. Added.

Comment: sir for the last can we put the format LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(TIME,'%l:%i %p')) for the IN and OUT

Comment: @Ashanti Of course. In output list, of course. Like ```.. SELECT .. COALESCE(LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(TIME,'%l:%i %p')), 'N/A') `IN`, ..```.

Comment: Sir, is not enough word to THANK YOU, I really appreciate your time to resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
          cte1 AS ( SELECT '2022-08-17' `date`
          UNION ALL
        SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          FROM cte1
          WHERE `date` < '2022-08-17'),
          cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT employee_name
          FROM `tabEmployee Checkin` )
          SELECT cte2.employee_name,
          DATE_FORMAT(cte1.`date`, '%e-%b-%y'),
          COALESCE(LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(t1.TIME,'%l:%i %p')), 'NA') `IN`,
          COALESCE(LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(t2.TIME,'%l:%i %p')), 'NA') `OUT`
        FROM cte1
          CROSS JOIN cte2
          LEFT JOIN `tabEmployee Checkin` t1 ON t1.employee_name = cte2.employee_name
                 AND cte1.`date` = DATE(t1.`time`)
                 AND t1.log_type = 'IN'
          LEFT JOIN `tabEmployee Checkin` t2 ON t2.employee_name = cte2.employee_name
                 AND cte1.`date` = DATE(t2.`time`)
                 AND t2.log_type = 'OUT'
        ORDER BY 1,2;
```

how to add WHERE status = Active to the above script

Thanks